# i have "HubConnection.connectionClosed(null) called while in state HubConnectionState.connected" problem in flutter app for connecting signalR hub

Tags: c#, flutter, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-server-side

this my code into flutter app for connecting to signalR project made in Blazor server side app and Net Core 3.1
my web hub project works correctly but i have problem in android side for connection and working ;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:signalr_core/signalr_core.dart';

class SignalRProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    static List<UserMessageModel> messages = List<UserMessageModel>();

    static HubConnection connection = HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(
      'https://signal.domain.com/chatHub',
      HttpConnectionOptions(
        logging: (level, message) => print(message),
      ))
    .build();

Function(bool update) onMessagesUpdateCallback;

Future initSignalR() async {
    await connection.start();

    connection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message) async {
        print(message);
    if (onMessagesUpdateCallback != null) {
        onMessagesUpdateCallback(true);
  }
});

connection.on("ReceiveConnectedMessage", (message) async {
  print("Connecting...}");
  await connection.invoke('Init', args: [
    'notifApp',
    'mojarab',
    connection.connectionId,
    'notification_app'
  ]);
  print("connected SignalRProvider");
});

connection.on("ReceiveDisconnectedMessage", (message) async {
  print("SignalR disconnected");
  await connection.start();
});

Timer timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) async {
  if (connection.state == HubConnectionState.connected) {
    await connection
        .invoke('StayLiveMessage', args: ['mojarab app', 'i am alive']);
    print("I am Alive!");
  } else {
    await connection.start();
  }
});
}
}
```

this code is for my server side hub service with c# and blazor technology
signalR technology

```
using BI;
using Common.Utilities;
using Data;
using Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Messaging.Server.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private IMessageBusiness messageManager;
        private IUserBusiness userManager;

        public ChatHub(
            IMessageBusiness _messageManager, IUserBusiness _userManager
        )
        {
            messageManager = _messageManager;
            userManager = _userManager; ;
        }

        public async Task Init(string app, string user, string connection, string device)
        {
            await userManager.AddOrUpdateUser(app, user, connection, device, "users");

            await SendUserMessages(app, "", user);
        }

        public async Task StayLiveMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveLiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string jsonMessage)
        {
             await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", jsonMessage);

             await Clients.All.SendAsync("AndroidReceiveMessage", jsonMessage);
        }

        public async Task SendMessageToClient(string jsonMessage)
        {
            Entities.UserMessageModel message = 
                 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entities.UserMessageModel> 
                 (jsonMessage);

            var oUser = await userManager.getUser(message.app, message.user, "users");

            await messageManager.AddMessage(message, "messages");

            await SendUserMessages(message.app, message.category, message.user);
        }

        private async Task SendUserMessages(string app, string category, string user)
        {
            var userData = await userManager.getUser(app, user, "users");
            var userNotif = await userManager.getUser("notifApp", user, "users");

            if (userData != null)
            {
                var userMessages = await messageManager.GetMessages(app, user, "messages");

                if (userMessages != null && userMessages.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var msg in userMessages)
                    {
                        var note = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);

                        await Clients
                        .Client(userData.connection)
                        .SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", note);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (userNotif != null)
            {
                 var userMessages = await messageManager.GetAllAppsMessages(user, "messages");

                 if (userMessages != null && userMessages.Count() > 0)
                {
                     foreach (var msg in userMessages)
                     {
                    var note = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);

                    await Clients
                        .Client(userNotif.connection)
                        .SendAsync("AndroidReceiveMessage", note);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveConnectedMessage", Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await userManager.setDisconnectedUser(Context.ConnectionId, "users");

        if (exception != null)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveDisconnectedMessage", Context.ConnectionId + " : " + 
            exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveDisconnectedMessage", Context.ConnectionId);
        }
    }
    }
   }
```

this is error log

```
I/GED     ( 5022): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 24, 
oppidx_max 24, oppidx_min 0
I/flutter ( 5022): Starting HubConnection.
I/flutter ( 5022): Starting connection with transfer format 
'TransferFormat.text'.
I/flutter ( 5022): Sending negotiation request: 
https://signal.dinavision.org/chatHub/negotiate.
I/flutter ( 5022): Selecting transport 'HttpTransportType.webSockets'.
I/flutter ( 5022): (WebSockets transport) Connecting.
I/flutter ( 5022): WebSocket connected to 
wss://signal.dinavision.org/chatHub? 
id=3l6Pd4QpcKsTQEy0RnPlIw#.
I/flutter ( 5022): The HttpConnection connected successfully.
I/flutter ( 5022): Sending handshake request.
I/flutter ( 5022): (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 
'32'.
I/flutter ( 5022): Using HubProtocol 'json'.
I/flutter ( 5022): (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of 
length  
'3'
I/flutter ( 5022): Server handshake complete.
I/flutter ( 5022): (WebSockets transport) data received. String data of 
length 
'85'
I/flutter ( 5022): connected : [3l6Pd4QpcKsTQEy0RnPlIw]
I/flutter ( 5022): HubConnection connected successfully.
I/flutter ( 5022): (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 
'115'.
I/flutter ( 5022): (WebSockets transport) socket closed.
I/flutter ( 5022): HttpConnection.stopConnection(null) called while in state 
ConnectionState.connected.
I/flutter ( 5022): Connection disconnected.
I/flutter ( 5022): HubConnection.connectionClosed(null) called while in state 
HubConnectionState.connected.
E/flutter ( 5022): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled 
Exception: Exception: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection 
being 
closed.
E/flutter ( 5022):
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make SignalRProvider a service you can inject, and not use a static variable for the hubconnection.

Comment: I/flutter (12149): (WebSockets transport) socket closed.
I/flutter (12149): HttpConnection.stopConnection(null) called while in state ConnectionState.connected.
I/flutter (12149): Connection disconnected.
I/flutter (12149): HubConnection.connectionClosed(null) called while in state HubConnectionState.connected.
E/flutter (12149): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed.
E/flutter (12149):

Answer (score 0):

I found that the asp.net core server side package might be updated to these.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common": "3.1.0.0",
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core": "1.1.0.0",
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "1.1.0.0",
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json": "3.1.1.7",
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "3.1.0.0",
Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets": "2.2.1",
```